# Change/Flip Player Sprite direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

currently I am working on a networked 2D platformer. I am trying to make the character always face in the direction he is walking. Therefore I am using this code: (BTW I know this is not supposed to work)

```
if (rigidbody.velocity.y > 0) {
        transform.rotation = 0,0,0;
} else if (rigidbody.velocity.y < 0) {
        transform.rotation = 0,180,0;
}
```

So my question would be what code would I have to use to make the character's transform's rotation be 0,0,0 when his velocity on the y axis is over zero and 0,180,0 when its under.

Note:
Yes I do know there are other ways of approaching this but I think this would be the ideal way in this instance and I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways to flip/change the direction where the character is facing:

**1**.You can use this variable on from the `SpriteRenderer`:

```
spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
//OR flipY for the Y-axis
spriteRenderer.flipY = true;
```

**2**.OR Multiple the axis you want to flip by `-1`.

```
Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y);
newPos.x = newPos.x * -1; //Flip X
transform.localScale = newPos;
```

Comment: thanks, great answer and best of all quick. I will definetely accept when the timer is up

Comment: If possible, set the flipX of the spriterenderer instead of rotating the transform. There are some cases when it is not the best solution though.

Comment: That's right. Just OP just wanted to rotate an object. I added that and other ways to do it.